# How to pass binding.variables to a method inside a class in Groovy

Tags: groovy

i am new to groovy, trying to write a groovy which reads input values from a .csv file and performs certain actions.
I have a class defined inside the groovy and trying to access the variables from the .csv file by calling binding.variables and it doesnt look to be working.
when i try the same from a method which is part of the Groovy(not part of the class) it works fine. is there a way to pass the binding.variables to the method which is inside the class

```
          methodA(String a, String b){
          if(binding.variables.containsKey(a)){
            print something//Works fine
           }
          }

          Class A{
           methodB(String a, String b){
             if(binding.variables.containsKey(a)){//Doesnt work
            print something
           }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just pass binding into your class

```
class A{ 
    def binding 
    def methodB(){
         if(binding.variables.containsKey(a)){
         print something
     }
}
new A(binding:binding).methodB()
```

Comment: Thanks i tried this but doesnt work. My method has 3 arguments should i passthe binding as below or without arguments                                                                                                                            new A(binding:binding).methodB(String a, String b, String c)

Comment: Also what i noticed is even though i am passing the binding to my class the binding within my class doesnt have the methods which the binding outside the class has. binding with in the class has no method "binding.variables" it says unknown method